# How do you culture Cutibacterium acnes?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology

I've been thinking of culturing Cutibacterium acnes (old name is Propionibacterium acnes) for a thesis topic of mine on the comparison of the efficacy of local antibacterial topical skin care products but I have no idea how to culture it. I haven't encountered any definite instructions on the process in culturing it aside from it being an aerotolerant anaerobe and requring an anaerobic incubator.

Answer (score 1):

Douglas & Gunter (1946) *The Taxonomic Position of Corynebacterium acnes.* J Bacteriol 52: [15-23](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16561149).

This is the paper, in which *Corynebacterium acnes* was proposed to be transferred to the genus *Propionibacterium* as *Propionibacterium acnes*, and it contains a detailed description of the cultivation procedure.